# Show that the if a sequence is bounded then show that the two sequences that make it up are bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show given $z_n = x_n + y_n$ and $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are both strictly increasing sequences, show that if $(z_n)$ is bounded above, then $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ is bounded above.

This is what I have so far:
If $(z_n)$ is bounded above, then $\exists M$ such that $z_n \leq M$ and $M$ is an upper bound for $(z_n)$. Since $z_n = x_n + y_n$, then $x_n + y_n \leq M$.

So, this means that $M$ is an upper bound for $x_n + y_n$. However, how can I show that both $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ is bounded above?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Following on from what you have already done, if $(y_n)$ is increasing then $$x_n\le M-y_n\le M-y_1\ .$$

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I'm still not really sure where to go from here. Can you give me an other hint for this hint? Thank you!

Comment: @Masha So, $x_n \le M - y_1$ for all $n$, making $(x_n)$ bounded above by the constant $M - y_1$. Try doing the same for $(y_n)$.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you! So for $(y_n)$ if $(x_n)$ is increasing then $y_n \leq M - x_n \leq M - x_1$ and then it follows from the same logic as above that $(y_n)$ is bounded above by the constant $M - x_1$$ ?

Comment: @Masha that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

If either of $x_n$ or $y_n$ were unbounded, then it would not be possible to put a bound on $z_n = x_n + y_n$. Thus they must be bounded.

Comment: If $x_n = -y_n$ for all $n$ then it is possible that $x_n$ is bounded below but not bounded above and similarly $y_n$ is bounded above and not below, and $z_n =x_n + y_n \equiv 0$

Comment: $x_n$ and $y_n$ are both strictly increasing so this cannot be the case.

Comment: Right. My mistake. I thought you were referencing the general case.